# Use cases Semigroupal and Apply in Scala Cats

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

Given the two chapters in Herding Cats, [semigroupal](https://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Semigroupal.html) and [apply](https://eed3si9n.com/herding-cats/Apply.html), I can't seem to find some use cases for them. Could you provide some examples of when to use which?

Comment: They allow you to do things like `(fa, fb, fc).mapN((a, b, c) => d)` and return an **F[D]**. A common example is combining multiple independent validations to build a final value of all validations passed or accumulate all errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For example, you could run two futures in parallel if they are independent and then combine their result

```
cats.Apply[Future].map2(Future(1), Future(41))(_ + _)
```

instead of

```
Future(1).flatMap(a => Future(41).map(b => a + b))
```

where inner `Future(41)` has to wait for the outer `Future(1)` to complete first.

`Semigroupal` provides single capability, namely, `product` which

> Combine an `F[A]` and an `F[B]` into an `F[(A, B)]`

for example

```
cats.Semigroupal[Future].product(Future(1), Future(42))
// res0: Future[(Int, Int)] = Future(Success((1,42)))
```

which in itself arguably is not very useful, but when combined with `Functor` we get the ability to map over the product so now we can perform computations on the effectful products, hence `Apply[A]` is a  made a subtype of both `Functor[A]` and `Semigroupal[A]`, for example

```
implicitly[Apply[Future] <:< (Functor[Future] with Semigroupal[Future])] // ok
```